# Невидимые UI кнопки Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу реализовать в приложении управление нажатием на правую и левую часть экрана. Поставил UI Button, у них есть в библиотеке UIMask, почти полностью прозрачные с ним. Но почти. Белесая пелена, видно их. Есть ли возможность сделать их полностью невидимыми, или как то отработать нажатие на правую и левую часть экрана?

Comment: Нажатие пальцами? А имеется в виду вообще в любом месте правой и левой части экрана или на кнопки, находящиеся на той и другой стороне?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я использовал кнопки так как самое очевидное решение. Сделал 2 кнопки, растянул их от края до центра каждую и всё ок, но они не идеально прозрачные. Надо либо их сделать невидимыми, либо продумать другой способ обрабатывать нажатия. Да, пальцами на таче. Да, в любом месте, главное чтобы левая и правая часть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как мне кажется, можно сделать проще, чем навешивать кнопки на экран.
Прикосновения должны детектиться в любом месте экрана, а значит логика проста: если координата прикосновения по X левее середины экрана - значит можно делать то, что запланировано делать слева. Если координата прикосновения по X правее середины экрана - значит можно делать то, что запланировано делать справа.

На языке программирования будет как-то так:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
     var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
     if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2) {
         DoLeftSideStuff();
     } else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2) {
         DoRightSideStuff();
     }
}
```

Должно работать.

Если ищется среди нескольких нажатий, то делаем в цикле перебор прикосновений:

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
   if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2) {
       DoLeftSideStuff();
   } else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2) {
       DoRightSideStuff();
   } 
}
```

..ит из соу симпл....

Answer (score 1):

Настройте у кнопки для всех цветов прозрачность (Alpha) в 0/255 и будет вам счастье
Сначала через контекстное меню создаем в сцене кнопку `ПКМ / UI/Button`. Теперь в появившейся кнопке заходим в потомки и деактивируем `Text`. Дальше переходим в главный объект находим скрипт `Image`, жмем в поле `Color` и у цвета нижнюю полоску с буквой `А` выставляем в `0`. Теперь кнопку не видно, но работать она работает. Для надежности можно еще в скрипте `Button` изменить также все существующие цвета на цвета с `Alpha = 0`.

Comment: Да я бы не против, но я нашёл там только выбор из готовых. Можете более подробно расписать по шагам?